# Cannot install google-api-python-client on QPython

Tags: google-api-python-client, qpython

I am not able to successfully install google-api-python-client through pip within QPython on Android.

Below is my pip log to give you the details of the issue.

---

```
Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/f7/83/377e3dd2e95f9020dbd0dfd3c47aaa7deebe3c68d3857a4e51917146ae8b/pyasn1-0.1.9.tar.gz#md5=f00a02a631d4016818659d1cc38d229a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyasn1/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyasn1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/build/pyasn1/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
        doclines = [ x.strip() for x in __doc__.split('\n') if x ]
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/build/pyasn1/setup.py", line 58, in <module>

    doclines = [ x.strip() for x in __doc__.split('\n') if x ]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 980, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 216, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 255, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Looks like your installation failed when it was installing pyasn1.

Actually qpython provided another way to install pyasn1.

Click the package button on the home page, install pyasn1 with qpypi, then run pip install again may solve it.

Hope this help! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for that tip. Sure! i did try that out which you mentioned. That worked well. However, later when I tried installing google-api-python-client, it failed with the same error message which I reported earlier. 
Same situation prevails! did not understand why. Any idea?

Comment: There were 2 packages of pyasn1 which had to be installed. Earlier I had installed only one. After this when I installed google-api-python-client, everything went smooth. I must say it was a major achievement in terms of me being able to run my python program on android. Thanks Again.